# How to apply a defined function to many rows?

Tags: python, function, sentiment-analysis, review

I would like to apply the defined function "tokenization" to all rows of the column "Review Gast" of the dataset "reviews_english". How can i do that? Currenty i can only apply it to one row. Thanks! :)

```
def tokenization(text):
    # Normalize
    text = normalize(text)

    # Remove Punctuation
    text = remove_punctuation(text)

    # Tokenize
    tokens = text.split()

    # Remove Stopwords
    tokens = remove_stopwords(tokens)

    # Apply Bag-of-Words (set of tokens)
    bow = set(tokens)

    return bow

clean_reviews_english =tokenization(reviews_english["Review Gast"][0])
print(clean_reviews_english)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list comprehension

```
clean_reviews_english = tokenization(review for review in reviews_english["Review Gast"])
```

or `map`:

```
clean_reviews_english = map(tokenization, reviews_english["Review Gast"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a pandas dataframe, if you want to apply a function to a column use `df["col"].apply(func)`

In this example, to add the results as a new column, use:

```
reviews_english["tokenized"] = reviews_english["Review Gast"].astype(str).apply(tokenization)
```

If you are not using a pandas dataframe, then use Corralien's answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I applied it - however, this error occured:
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: Try enforcing that the data is a string. Perhaps one of the reviews is just a number like "5.0" for five stars and it is getting interpreted as a string. I have modified the code to do this using .astype(str)

Comment: Thank you so much - it worked! :) Sadly, i can give you no upvode since i do have to little responses.

Comment: Thats okay, glad to hear it. You can press the tick button to accept this answer I belive though :)